# Get if a coordinate is inside a polyline

Tags: php, maps, coordinates

Given a polyline of coordinates in a map, how can I know if a coordinate is inside this polyline or not ?

For example, in this image:

[image: polywantcracker]

How can I know if 40.744818,-73.989701 (per example), is inside or not ?

Best if in PHP :P

Thank you !

Comment: Do you want to reinvent the algorithm or are you looking for a library (in which case, google some, there's a bunch out there)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question already solved (with javascript), please read: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26225/solving-the-point-in-polygon-problem-using-google-maps-and-fusion-tables

And here is the matemathical description:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon, here is some different algorithms, what you can use. I recommend you the `Ray casting algorithm` (`RCA`) from here:
http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Ray-casting_algorithm

There is a pseudo code what you could implement in php ;)

For solving mathematical problems, recommend to browse this project: http://www.phpmath.com/home
And hoping you can find an implemented php solution for your problem ;)

And if you need more performance, you could look after `collusion detection` in 2D. 
The first step: Create an outer rectalgle around your polygon, see is the point insde in the rectangle. If inside, you have chance that your point is inside the poly, and than run the `Ray Casting Algorithm`. See:

```
$px //the x coordinate of your point
$py //the y coordinate of your point
$ppy //the y coordinates of points of your polygon (in the correct order)
$ppx //the x coordinates of points of your polygon (in the correct order)

$isInside = 
    (max($ppy)>$py && min($ppy)<$px && max($ppx)>$px && min($ppy)<$px)?
    RCA($px,$py,$ppx,$ppy): 
    false;    
}

/**
 * @description decide, is a point in poligon
 * @param float $px the x coordinate of your point
 * @param float $py the y coordinate of your point
 * @param array(float) $ppx the x coordinates of the points of polygon
 *             array(x1,x2,...) 
 * @param array(float) $ppy the y coordinates of the points of polygon
 *             array(y1,y2,...) 
 *             points of polygon: [x1,y1],[x2,y2],...
 * @return boolean : Is the point inside the polygon?
 */
function RCA($px,$py,array $ppx,array $ppy){
      //the implementation
}
```

(If in your use, there is a lot of coordinates outside from the outer rectangle, this code run faster. The 2 `max`, 2 `min` , 2 `<` and 2 `>` condition testing is more faster than `RCA`, and if a point is outside the rectangle, no need to run `RCA`)

(The solution below is not object orientated. If you use `OOP` the solution could be nicer:))

A help link where is an implementation in php:
http://assemblysys.com/php-point-in-polygon-algorithm/ (not exactly what i wrote, but should work)

Comment: I will look for your "wiki's" URL's ... I don't want to use google Maps (since it's on server side). THANK YOU ! ;)

Comment: Nice job ;) i add this to the answer, to help others who have same question ;)